# Is there a single-word verb meaning “to perform cunnilingus on”?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

The single word for *to perform fellatio on* is the verb *fellate*.

Is there an analogous word for cunnilingus?

Comment: Without trying to get too vulgar here, the term "to eat-out" is widely used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OED provides the obvious answer for the corresponding verb under its headword for the noun ***cunnilingus***, which is of course ***(to) cunnilingue***:

> ### **ˈcunnilingue** *v. trans.* and *intr.*
>
> to practise cunnilingus (on).
>
> - **1887 L. C. Smithers** tr. Forberg’s *Man. Class. Erotology* v. 122 
>    A man who is in the habit of putting out his tongue for the obscene act of cunnilinging.
> - **1905 Havelock Ellis** *Stud. Psychol. Sex.* IV. 21 
>    Cunnilingus was a very familiar manifestation in classic times;..it tends to be especially prevalent at all periods of high civilization.
> - **1969 G. Legman** *Rationale of Dirty Joke* viii. 566 
>    A man comes home and finds the vicar cunnilinguing his wife.

The OED does provide other citations as well, but those should suffice to illustrate the matter without risking too much undue titillation or cachinnation in those prone to such.

If one were prone to abstruse extended senses and polypuns, I suppose that *cunnilingue* might also be what one does during a notably succulent course of Hasenpfeffer.

Comment: Aha! This is the answer. I'm surprised I couldn't find this word on any non-community online dictionaries.

Comment: On the subject of titillation...  **Q:** How do you titillate an ocelot?  **A:**  Oscillate its tit a lot.

Answer (score 9):

There's a good old-fashioned word (popular in Victorian erotica, but sadly fallen out of favor) that covers both fellatio and cunnilingus: **[gamahuche](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gamahuche)**.  Let's bring it back!

It's a transitive verb ("I'm going to *gamahuche* her") as well as a noun ("She says I give great *gamahuche*.")

Comment: This is probably the best answer. While it's not a perfect fit for what I was looking for, it's a real, non-slang single verb.

Comment: Absolutely great answer - love the word, and I might even try to slip it into regular personal use. It is probably not-done to remark on the appropriateness of a username with regard to the given answer, so I will refrain from that.

Comment: @oerkelens - Hmm. Hadn't thought of that...

Comment: Dean Wesley Smith used it in his short-story Cutting Down Fred.  http://www.wmgpublishinginc.com/project/cutting-down-fred/ (included in the Dinosaur Fantastic anthology).  Funny coincidence to stumble on this question within a day of listening to the audiobook of that story.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Ain't synchronicity great?

Comment: *Popular in Victorian erotica?* I just checked Google Books for [pre-1900 instances of **gamahuche**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22gamahuche%22#q=%22gamahuche%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&*). There are a couple of dozen hits, but almost every one of them is a ***French*** text. There's only one C19 instance of it as an Anglicized tensed verb - [she gamahuched men](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22that+she+gamahuched+men%22), which is the opposite of OP's sought meaning.

Comment: The very first hit in your Google Books search is an 1888 book called "My Secret Life".  In the table of contents (and the heading of Chapter II) there's an entry* entitled "Gamahuching", which - if you then read pages 43 and 44 - refers exclusively to cunnilingus.

*By the way - what are those references called?  My first exposure to them was in Mark Twain; I've often wished that they hadn't gone out of fashion.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

In the vernacular of American English, and when taken in the proper context, "ate" would seem to be an appropriate **single** word when used in a sentence like: "He ate her pussy"; it being understood that reference wasn't being made to a meal made of the resident feline.

Comment: While technically this answer is correct, it feels like slang to me, so it doesn't quite fit the context I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [cunnilinguate](http://www.definition-of.com/cunnilinguate).

> [cunnilinguate](http://pt.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cunnilinguate): to perform cunnilingus (or [cunnilinctus](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cunnilingus))

Comment: Given your first two links, this seems like a made-up word. I _wish_ this were the right word, because it perfectly fits the context I was looking for.